# How to decode a JSON unicode escaped entry from Facebook in python?

Tags: python, json, facebook, unicode, encoding

I am using FQL facebook interface to retrieve some information from users. I just came across a field that I don't know how to decode.

One user has the subsequent `current_location` field:

```
u'{"city": u"\\xc1vila", "name": u"\\xc1vila, Castilla y Le\\xf3n, Spain", 
"zip": "", "country": "Spain", "longitude": -4.7, "state": "Castilla y Leon", 
"latitude": 40.65, "id": 113972385284243}'
```

When trying `json.loads()` it fails with `*** ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

I've tried to decode with several options but dont seem to find the right option.

Any lead on how to approach the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do **not** have JSON data there, you have a *Python* string literal there.

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get a Python object again:

```
>>> import ast
>>> value = u'{"city": u"\\xc1vila", "name": u"\\xc1vila, Castilla y Le\\xf3n, Spain", "zip": "", "country": "Spain", "longitude": -4.7, "state": "Castilla y Leon", "latitude": 40.65, "id": 113972385284243}'
>>> ast.literal_eval(value)
{'city': u'\xc1vila', 'name': u'\xc1vila, Castilla y Le\xf3n, Spain', 'zip': '', 'country': 'Spain', 'longitude': -4.7, 'state': 'Castilla y Leon', 'latitude': 40.65, 'id': 113972385284243}
```

You need to look into how you got that string in the first place. I suspect you stored the `repr()` output of the `json.loads()` result somewhere.

Comment: I suspect (because of the `\\xc1` bit) that the `u'…'` is actually part of the string, meaning he probably stored the `repr` somewhere… in which case he may have to call `literal_eval` twice to recover the original object…

Comment: @abarnert: no, the output is correct with one decode; it could be the `repr()` was stored and retrieved as unicode..

Comment: You are completely right! It was wrongly stored before and that was the result. Your solution fixes the issue but I will dig a little bit to find why it is stored that way. Thanks a lot @MartijnPieters

Comment: @MartijnPieters: My point is that I think he could actually have `value = 'u\'{"city": u"\\\\xc1vila", "name": u"\\\\xc1vila, Castilla y Le\\\\xf3n, Spain","zip": "", "country": "Spain", "longitude": -4.7, "state": "Castilla y Leon","latitude": 40.65, "id": 113972385284243}\''`. If he did a `print value` with that, it would look like what he posted in the question.